# Uncaught TypeError: not a function when calling method from data in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I get an error: "Uncaught TypeError: this.thePerson is not a function" when I run this:

```
var myApp = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        person: [this.thePerson()]
    },
    methods: {
        thePerson: function() {
            return {
                personNickname: "Bob",
                personOwes: 0,
                paymentType: {
                    card: true,
                    cash: false
                }
            };
        }
    }
});
```

I can't figure out why!

P.S. I realize this is weird looking code but there's a reason why I'm using a function to return the array contents...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you try, assigning persons value on Vue's created method ?

according to your example:

```
    var myApp = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      person: []
  },
  methods: {
      thePerson: function() {
          return {
              personNickname: "Bob",
              personOwes: 0,
              paymentType: {
                  card: true,
                  cash: false
              }
          };
      }
  },
  created(){
    this.person.push(this.thePerson())
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually worked. @eric-guan please see that this is how I solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Turn `data` into a function.

```
var myApp = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: function() {
        return {
            person: [this.thePerson()]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        thePerson: function() {
            return {
                personNickname: "Bob",
                personOwes: 0,
                paymentType: {
                    card: true,
                    cash: false
                }
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `this` is the context of a function. You were using `this` outside of a function. If your code ran in the browser, `this` would be `window`, and not your component. Always declare `data` as a function, no matter what, even if you aren't using `this`. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data

Comment: Check out this slightly built-out code: https://jsfiddle.net/k0cxth61/1/

The computed method is outputting "Undefined" but if "this" is now the correct context then why is it undefined?

Comment: You're not actually using the computed property. You're using the variable `getFirstName` which is undefined. You want `this.getFirstName`. Notice that it's a property, not a function/method, you don't call it with parentheses.

Comment: I see that error which I fixed but still no luck. I built this in a very clear CodePen for you to look at... https://codepen.io/rettoy/pen/ejoKmq

Comment: Seems like `data` is evaluated before `computed` is, so you can't reference computed properties in data. Which makes sense, since computed properties are derived values from `data`.